# Proof that $\cos(x) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\implies x = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

I know that $$\cos(x) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$ yields to $$(1)\qquad \qquad \qquad x = \frac{\pi}2 + 2k\pi$$ or $$(2)\qquad \qquad \qquad x = -\frac{\pi}2 + 2k\pi$$ which (as I found out in a textbook) is the same as $$x = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$$
My question is how (1) and (2) imply the last result, I would like an algebraic proof or demonstration.$\\$

I know it's obvious, but I couldn't find out a rigorous demonstration by myself to why it's the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi&=\begin{cases}\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi &\text{if $k=2n$}\\-\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi&\text{if $k=2n-1$}\end{cases}
\end{align*}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Maybe listing them for various $k$ will convince you:
$$\color{red}{ \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi=\dots-\frac{7\pi}{2},-\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2},\frac{9\pi}{2},\dots}$$
and
$$\color{blue}{-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi=\dots-\frac{5\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{7\pi}{2},\frac{11\pi}{2},\dots}$$

and

$$\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi=\dots\color{blue}{-\frac{5\pi}{2}},\color{red}{-\frac{3\pi}{2}},\color{blue}{-\frac{\pi}{2}},\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}},\color{blue}{\frac{3\pi}{2}},\color{red}{\frac{5\pi}{2}}\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

Let indicate with

- $x_1 = \frac{\pi}2 + 2k_1\pi$
- $x_2 = -\frac{\pi}2 + 2k_2\pi$
- $x_k = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$

then we need to prove that $\forall k_1 \; \exists k$ such that

$$x_k =x_1 \iff \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi = \frac{\pi}2 + 2k_1\pi \iff k=2k_1$$

and that $\forall k_2 \;\exists k$ such that

$$x_k =x_2 \iff \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi = -\frac{\pi}2 + 2k_2\pi \iff k=2k_2-1$$

and since $\forall k$ we have $\cos x_k=\cos \frac \pi 2$, we are done.